# Dynamic Oracle Type not visible in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have an oracle function that I use to update some data into the database from Java.

The Function:

```
 FUNCTION addFunc (
    contact_id              IN   NUMBER,
    contact_distrib_list       IN contact_array
                )
 RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

The array type is declared in the package as

```
TYPE contact_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Now,
I am trying to call this Function from my Java code.

```
ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor =  ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("contact_array", sqlConnection);
```

But, when i try to do the above it complains that the type is not recognized.

> java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: contact_array

I tried all the ways to supply a sql name here. I tried the schema name.package name.array name etc. But still the same error.

Am I incorrectly defining the type in oracle?

Is there any other way of connecting using Java JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a PL/SQL index-by table (also known as an associative array) to a stored procedure, you will need to use [Oracle extensions to JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraint.htm#BABBGDFA).  You cannot use `ArrayDescriptor` with index-by tables.

In particular, you will need to use the [`OracleCallableStatement.setPlsqlIndexTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraint.htm#BABCHCGF) method, for example:

```
((OracleCallableStatement)callableStatement).setPlsqlIndexTable(
    3, data, data.length, data.length, Types.VARCHAR, 100);
```

I'm assuming that the index-by table is parameter number 3 and that `data` contains the array of `String`s you wish to pass as the contents of the table.  The number `100` is the length of the elements within the collection.